# Azure sql - how to view table data (.net backend)

Tags: mysql, asp.net, azure

I have just started using Azure and i created a mobile app , setup a database and chose a .net backend .

I got a preconfigured backend folder which i downloaded and then published to my azure server.

However i have no idea how to verify in the azure portal if its working.

I can see my databases but not the actual tables and content .

I'm using .net backend so easytables are not supported .

Does Azure has something like phpmyadmin that lets me check the content of the database while i'm programming ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to the database with the usual Sql Server Management Studio tool, or directly from Visual studio using Server/Cloud explorer.  If its a SQL Azure database you're connecting to, you need first to find the management blade in the portal for the database and then add your client IP address to the firewall settings for that database server for you to be able to connect from your desktop.

ps. tagged with "MySQL" but title refers to Azure sql - I'm answering in terms of Azure SQL.

[Download SQL Server Management Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx)